# com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException: 100: Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)

Tags: spring-boot, postman, flickr

I want to use Spring with Flickr, but when I add a photo I receive this error "2023-12-16T12:53:58.182+01:00 ERROR 616 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException: 100: Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)] with root cause

com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException: 100: Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)
at com.flickr4java.flickr.uploader.Uploader.sendUploadRequest(Uploader.java:156) ~[flickr4java-3.0.8.jar:na]
at com.flickr4java.flickr.uploader.Uploader.upload(Uploader.java:107) ~[flickr4java-3.0.8.jar:na]
at project.sgs.Service.FlickrService.savePhoto(FlickrService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at project.sgs.Strategy.SaveArticlePhoto.savePhoto(SaveArticlePhoto.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at project.sgs.Strategy.SaveArticlePhoto.savePhoto(SaveArticlePhoto.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at project.sgs.Strategy.StrategyPhotoContext.SavePhoto(StrategyPhotoContext.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at project.sgs.Controller.PhotoController.save(PhotoController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]"

```
package project.sgs.Config;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.REST;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.RequestContext;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.auth.Auth;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.auth.Permission;
import com.github.scribejava.apis.FlickrApi;
import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1AccessToken;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1RequestToken;
import com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth10aService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class FlickrConfiguration {
    @Value("${flickr.apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;
    @Value("${flickr.apiSecret}")
    private String apisecret;
    @Value("${flickr.appKey}")
    private String appKey;
    @Value("${flickr.appSecret}")
    private String appsecret;
    private Flickr flickr;
   /* @Bean
    public Flickr getFlickr() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, FlickrException {
        Flickr flickr=new Flickr(apiKey,apisecret,new REST());
        OAuth10aService oAuth10aService=new ServiceBuilder(apiKey)
                .apiSecret(apisecret)
                .build(FlickrApi.instance(FlickrApi.FlickrPerm.DELETE));
        final Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        final OAuth1RequestToken oAuth1RequestToken=oAuth10aService.getRequestToken();
        final String authUrl=oAuth10aService.getAuthorizationUrl(oAuth1RequestToken);
        System.out.println(authUrl);
        System.out.println("paste it here >>");
        final String authVerifier=scanner.nextLine();
        OAuth1AccessToken oAuth1AccessToken=oAuth10aService.getAccessToken(oAuth1RequestToken,authVerifier);
        System.out.println(oAuth1AccessToken.getToken());
        System.out.println(oAuth1AccessToken.getTokenSecret());
        Auth auth=flickr.getAuthInterface().checkToken(oAuth1AccessToken);
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(auth.getToken());
        System.out.println(auth.getTokenSecret());
        return flickr;
    }*/
   @Bean
   public Flickr getFlickr(){
           flickr = new Flickr(apiKey, apisecret, new REST());
           Auth auth = new Auth();
           auth.setPermission(Permission.DELETE);
           auth.setToken(appKey);
           auth.setTokenSecret(appsecret);
           RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
           requestContext.setAuth(auth);
           flickr.setAuth(auth);
           return flickr;
       }
}
```

```
package project.sgs.Controller;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import project.sgs.Exeption.InvalidOperationExeption;
import project.sgs.Strategy.StrategyPhotoContext;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/photo")
public class PhotoController {
    @Autowired
    private StrategyPhotoContext strategyPhotoContext;
    @PostMapping("/save/{id}/{title}/{context}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String title, @PathVariable String context, @RequestPart MultipartFile photo) throws IOException, FlickrException, InvalidOperationExeption {
        Object objet=strategyPhotoContext.SavePhoto(context,id,photo.getInputStream(),title);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(objet, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

```
package project.sgs.Service;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.uploader.UploadMetaData;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.InputStream;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FlickrService {
    @Autowired
    private Flickr flickr;
    public String savePhoto(InputStream photo,String title) throws FlickrException {
        UploadMetaData uploadMetaData=new UploadMetaData();
        uploadMetaData.setTitle(title);
        String photoid=flickr.getUploader().upload(photo,uploadMetaData);
        return flickr.getPhotosInterface().getPhoto(photoid).getMedium640Url();
    }
}
```

```
package project.sgs.Strategy;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import project.sgs.Exeption.ErrorCode;
import project.sgs.Exeption.InvalidOperationExeption;

import java.io.InputStream;


@Service
public class StrategyPhotoContext {
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private Strategy strategy;
    @Setter
    private String context;
    @Autowired

    public StrategyPhotoContext(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
    public Object SavePhoto(String context, Long id, InputStream photo,String title) throws InvalidOperationExeption, FlickrException {
        determinContext(context);
        return strategy.savePhoto(id,photo,title);
    }

    private void determinContext(String context) throws InvalidOperationExeption {
        final String beanName=context+"Strategy";
        switch (context){
                case "article":
                    strategy=beanFactory.getBean(beanName,SaveArticlePhoto.class);
                    break;
                case "client":
                    strategy=beanFactory.getBean(beanName,SaveClientPhoto.class);
                    break;
                case "fournisseure":
                        strategy=beanFactory.getBean(beanName,SaveFournisseurePhoto.class);
                    break;
                case "utilisateure":
                    strategy=beanFactory.getBean(beanName,SaveUtilisateurePhoto.class);
                    break;
                case "entreprise":
                    strategy=beanFactory.getBean(beanName,SaveEntreprisePhoto.class);
                    break;
            default:throw new InvalidOperationExeption("conntext inconu", ErrorCode.Context_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package project.sgs.Strategy;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;

import java.io.InputStream;

public interface Strategy <T>{
    T savePhoto(Long id,InputStream photo,String titre) throws FlickrException;
}
```

```
package project.sgs.Strategy;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import project.sgs.Dto.ArticleDto;
import project.sgs.Service.ArticelService;
import project.sgs.Service.FlickrService;

import java.io.InputStream;
@Service("articleStrategy")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SaveArticlePhoto implements Strategy<ArticleDto>{
    @Autowired
    private FlickrService flickrService;
    @Autowired
    private ArticelService articelService;
    @Override
    public ArticleDto savePhoto(Long id, InputStream photo, String titre) throws FlickrException {
        ArticleDto article=articelService.getArticleById(id);
        String UrlPhoto=flickrService.savePhoto(photo,titre);
        article.setPhoto(UrlPhoto);
        return articelService.saveArticle(article);
    }
}
```

```
lickr.apiKey=2d5de463eea9a98a698ad01861cbb58f
flickr.apiSecret=a2eb4b637b8f9c60
flickr.appKey=72157720903774158-1d3546a3852db77b
flickr.appSecret=9283c70e54b9a6cb
```

`and this is URl testing with postman:http://localhost:8080/photo/save/1/aymen/article`

[this is state of app flicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Bkf.png)